# Push a new view when a cell is tapped in Table View

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

Hey guys,
I have a Table View that has been populated with 21 data:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Glossary", @"Back");

        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Title", @"Meta Description Tag", @"Meta Keywords", @"Headings", @"Images", @"Frames", @"Flash Contents", @"Charset", @"Favicon", @"W3C Compatibility", @"Page Rank", @"Alexa Rank", @"Indexed Pages", @"Latest Date Cached By Google", @"Backlinks", @"Dmoz Listing", @"Server Info", @"IP", @"Location", @"Server Type", @"Registrar Info", nil];
        self.glossaryArray = array;
        [array release];
    }


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 4;
    }

    // Category
    - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if (section == 0) return @"In-Site SEO";
        if (section == 1) return @"Inside Analysis";
        if (section == 2) return @"Ranks N Stuff";
        if (section == 3) return @"Server Info";
        return @"Other";
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        if (section == 0) return 7;
        if (section == 1) return 3;
        if (section == 2) return 6;
        if (section == 3) return 5;
        return 0;
    }

    // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        // Configure the cell...
        NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
        if ( indexPath.section == 1 ) row += 7;
        if ( indexPath.section == 2 ) row += 10;
        if ( indexPath.section == 3 ) row += 16;
        if ( indexPath.section == 4 ) row += 21;
        cell.textLabel.text = [glossaryArray objectAtIndex:row];

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        return cell;
    }

Now this is the code I used to pussh a new view when a cell is tapped:

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
        if (self.glossaryDetailViewController == nil) {
            GlossaryDetailViewController *aGlossaryDetail = [[GlossaryDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GlossaryDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
            self.glossaryDetailViewController = aGlossaryDetail;
            [aGlossaryDetail release];
        }

        glossaryDetailViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [glossaryArray objectAtIndex:row]];

        NewReferencemoi_caAppDelegate *delegate = (NewReferencemoi_caAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [delegate.glossaryNavController pushViewController:glossaryDetailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

This code works perfectly, but the problem is that each and all 21 elements in my table view is opening the one and same nib file that I created. Basically, I want to create 1 UIViewController for each of my 21 elements, where each have their own description of the element, not just using 1 UIViewController for all elements in my Table View, and when each element has been tapped, each open their own view. Apparently, I don't know how to code in that part, so I hope someone can help me out with this part of my iPhone project, thanks

Comment: You should have edited your old question instead of opening a new one with the same goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please do not create 21 different view controllers just to show different items. Instead set a property on `GlossaryDetailViewController` that holds an instance of your data model item.

Consider this...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];

    if (self.glossaryDetailViewController == nil)
    {
        GlossaryDetailViewController *aGlossaryDetail = [[GlossaryDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GlossaryDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.glossaryDetailViewController = aGlossaryDetail;
        [aGlossaryDetail release];
    }

    glossaryDetailViewController.glossaryDetailItem = [glossaryArray objectAtIndex:row];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.glossaryDetailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Using this approach makes `GlossaryDetailViewController` responsible for setting it's own data.

**Edit**
You'll also notice that I removed references to the app delegate. You don't need it to get access to the navigation controller. Each view controller in a navigation controller stack has a reference to it. While I'm thoroughly tearing your code apart, I would also factor out the creation of the view controller by overriding the getter for `glossaryDetailViewController`, like this:

```
- (GlossaryDetailViewController *)glossaryDetailViewController
{
    if (!glossaryDetailViewController)
    {
        glossaryDetailViewController = [[GlossaryDetailViewController alloc] init];
    }

    return glossaryDetailViewController;
}
```

If you go this route, you can remove the `if` statement and just call `self.glossaryDetailViewController`.

Comment: hey thanks, do you have like an example of how to hold an instance of a data for each cell? Thanks

Comment: Sure, you subclass NSObject to make an object that will hold all of your related data that will be shown on `glossaryDetailViewController`. Then you would create your `glossaryArray` to hold those objects instead of NSStrings as you have now. Additionally you will add `glossaryDetailItem` as a property of `glossaryDetailViewController` with the same type.

Comment: wow thanks, now that I am using this code, I ran into one tiny problem, I'm getting `glossaryDetailViewController.glossaryDetailItem = [glossaryArray objectAtIndex:row];` error because it's saying: Error: request for member 'aGlossaryDetail' in something not a structure or union. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Take what you have now and roll it into a new question. I'd need to see more code to understand what's going on here.