# View controllers from table cell items

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

At the moment I have a table with 5 cells each of which is labeled. When a cell is tapped its linked to a new view where information is displayed, my question is do I have to have 5 separate view controllers to show the information? also is there a way to push new views from table cells without using static cells, thats the method I could make work, is it the correct one?

Comment: using static cells segued to new views in storyboards btw

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571686/push-a-new-view-when-a-cell-is-tapped-in-table-view?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

in the code (of your tableViewController) where you push, pass the new ViewController the selected row for example.

for detailed code see : [Push a new view when a cell is tapped in Table View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571686/push-a-new-view-when-a-cell-is-tapped-in-table-view?rq=1)

Comment: dont really understand it properly, until i look into it and test it out, will that work? and do i have to implement or add anything other than the sample code in that other answer?